# ActiveMQ doesn't start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

One of the packages which seems to be plagued with problems is `activemq`.

After installing it, it's necessary to enable one of the queues with a simple symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/activemq/instances-available/main \
    /etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main
```

Next, start the service:

```
sudo service activemq start
```

Is it running?

```
ps aux | grep '[a]ctive'
```

Nope. Maybe it's not showing up properly?

```
ps aux | grep '[j]ava'
```

Nope.

Start it up in foreground mode:

```
sudo activemq console
```

Great, classpath errors right out of the box [(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/xH4A1GRi):

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 25 more
```

How do I fix what's wrong with ActiveMQ so I can get it to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible solution, but I simply started using Ubuntu 12.04 and ActiveMQ "just works™."

Comment: Not the solution-droid I'm looking for.

Comment: I am a different David K, and this is not the solution-droid I'm looking for, either.